# there is a restapi which is i have to install in my folder

Tags: python, reactjs

```
PS C:\Users\ds\desktop> cd frontend
PS C:\Users\ds\desktop\frontend> npx create-react-app myapp
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ds\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ds\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ds\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-08T10_53_23_756Z-debug-0.log
```

please help in this .i cant install react in my file

Comment: Are you sure NodeJs and npm are installed on your system?

Comment: The error message clearly says that it cannot find the npm executable. I'd first check if `npm` command is available, then try to uninstall-then-reinstall `npm`, `npx` and `node` altogether. bear in mind that after a successful installation, you may need to start a new terminal to see the change in effect.